# Prove that $f$ is differentiable on $\Bbb R^n$ and $Df(x)=0$ for all $x\in \Bbb R^n$ and $f$ is constant.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

For a function $f : \Bbb R^n → \Bbb R^n$, there exist a constant $M > 0$ and a constant
$α > 1$ such that, $|f(y) − f(x)| ≤ M|y − x|^{\alpha}$ for all $x,y\in \Bbb R^n$. Prove that $f$ is differentiable on $\Bbb R^n$ and $Df(x)=0$ for all $x\in \Bbb R^n$ and $f$ is constant.

**My try**

Observe that for $n=1$ it is easy because $Df(x)$ is just a scalar so arithmetic can be applied directly that $|\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}|\leqslant M|x-y|^{\alpha-1}\to 0$ [ since $\alpha-1>0$], $ as $x \to y$(\forall x\in\mathbb{R}):f'(x)=0.$

In higher dimension I have to show that $Df(x)$ exist. So I started with a linear transformation $A=0$ and we can show that $$\frac{||f(y)-f(x)-A(x-y)||}{||y-x||}|\leqslant M|x-y|^{\alpha-1}\to 0$$

then we are done right!

Comment: I think that you already proved it XD!

Comment: Yeah that's why I put it under proof verification and at the end I said "Am I right?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x\in\mathbb{R^n}$. We have to show that for the operator $A=0$ we have:

$f(x+h)=f(x)+Ah+o(|h|)$ as $h\to 0$

Equivalently, we have to show that $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{|h|}$ tends to $0$ as $h\to 0$. And indeed:

$\frac{|f(x+h)-f(x)|}{|h|}\leq M\frac{|h|^{\alpha}}{|h|}=M |h|^{\alpha-1}\to 0$

So indeed $f$ is differentiable at the point $x$, and the derivative is the zero operator.